# Read Serialized Array as Shortcode Argument

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Event Manager plugin with Advanced Custom Fields plugin In WordPress.

In my events post type, I have added an image gallery with ACF and want to display the first image in the events list page created by Events Manager. The only way I can do that within the events list is by creating a shortcode that will read the serialized array returned from the custom field which is usually something like `a:1:{i:0;s:4:"6903";}`.

```
function unseralLink( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts, 'unseralizeLink');
    if($atts['id']!='')
        {
        $mydata =  unserialize($atts['id']);
        $url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($mydata[0]);
        return "<img src=\"".$url."\" alt=\"\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail\" />";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'unseralizeLink', 'unseralLink' );
```

I call the shortcode with `[unseralizeLink id="#_ATT{gallery}"]`. But nothing gets returned.

What I really need help with is reading the serialized array as a shortcode argument and storing it to a local variable within the function. After that, I should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting I found the solution.

```
function eventImgURL( $atts ) {
shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );
    $myvar = unserialize($atts[id]);
    return wp_get_attachment_image($myvar[0]);

}
add_shortcode( 'unseralizelink', 'eventImgURL' );
```

Part of the issue was that I was calling the serialized array using double quotes in the shortcode when double quotes were used.

```
[unseralizelink id='#_ATT{gallery}']
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and the solution the asker posted wouldn't work. Here's mine, working nicely, for the next one having the same problem:

```
function eventImgURL( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'id' => '',), $atts, 'unserialize-link' );
    return wp_get_attachment_image($atts['id']);
}
add_shortcode( 'unserialize-link', 'eventImgURL' );
```

Then call it in your HTML template as follows:

```
<p>[unserialize-link id='#_ATT{logo}']</p>
```

See the [documentation on shortcodes from the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) for more information.